# Configuring SSTP client on Debian

Tags: debian, vpn

I would need to connect my Debian (stable) server to a Windows Server 2008R2 server, which is acting as a SSTP VPN server. I have managed to install [sstp-client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/) on my Debian server, but I do not know how to configure the connection so that I can run it in the background. Furthermore, there are quite many things that I do not understand about the whole configuration process.

Following some advice I found on the Internet, I disabled authentication of remote server by adding `noauth` to `/etc/ppp/options`. Furthermore, I added there the options `refuse-pap`, `refuse-eap`, `refuse-chap`, `refuse-mschap` and `require mppe` to force MS-CHAP-v2 authentication (the Windows server is configured to accept that and not the others).

If I run from terminal

`sstpc --log-level 4 --log-stderr --user USERNAME --password PASSWORD SERVER_IP`

the connection works, and opening another terminal, I can access a web page that can only be accessed over the VPN.

I have tried to create the file `etc/ppp/peers/sstp-1` with the contents

```
remotename sstp-1
linkname sstp-1
ipparam sstp-1
pty "sstpc --ipparam sstp-1 --log-level 4 --save-server-route --nolaunchpppd --user USERNAME --password PASSWORD SERVER_IP"
name USERNAME
plugin sstp-pppd-plugin.so
sstp-sock /var/run/sstpc/sstpc-sstp-1
usepeerdns
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mppe
noauth
```

and then running from the command line `sudo pon sstp-1`. The connection fails, and `sudo plog` shows

```
pppd[4813]: Plugin sstp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
pppd[4814]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
pppd[4814]: Using interface ppp0
pppd[4814]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
pppd[4814]: Could not connect to sstp-client (/var/run/sstpc/sstpc-sstp-1), Connection refused (111)
pppd[4814]: Exit.
```

I have couple of questions regarding all this:

1. How to set up the `/etc/ppp/peers/sstp-1` so that I can connect/disconnect to the VPN in background (to be used in a script)?
2. The Windows server encrypts the VPN traffic using a self-signed certificate. Why, using the above connection configuration, I do not need to install the certificate on the client machine? Is the traffic encrypted at all?

Thank you already in advance,
Joel Lehikoinen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. What broke the config was providing `--user` and `--password` as command line options on the line beginning with `pty`. The username is already given on the next line and password should be provided in `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`. The problem was fixed by changing that line to

   ```
   pty "sstpc --ipparam sstp-1 --nolaunchpppd SERVER_IP"
   ```

   in addition, there is no need to edit `/etc/ppp/options`, since the configuration parameters are already given in the SSTP config file `/etc/ppp/peers/sstp-1`
2. It would seem that, at least with the `noauth` option, which I thought would only disable the server authentication in PPP, sstp-client also **accepts a self-signed SSL server certificate** without any complaints.

   As a work-around, one possibility seems to be creating a self-signed CA certificate, signing the server certificate with that, and providing `--ca-cert /path/to/snakeoil-ca.pem` as a command-line options to sstp-client (i.e., on the "pty" line of the file), which constraints the server SSL certificate to a known value.